# How do I set up an arraylist to it's child components in XML Deserializing?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

Here is my XML:

```
<Plan>
  <Id>default</Id>
  <Layout>default</Layout>
  <Zones>
    <Zone>
      <Id>123</Id>
    </Zone>
    <Zone>
      <Id>456</Id>
    </Zone>
    <Zone>
      <Id>789</Id>
    </Zone>
</Plan>
```

Here is my C# class system to try to deserialize this code:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Plan
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Zone
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Right now when I deserialize, it will deserialize Plan -> Id but not Plan -> Zones.  What do I need to change in my C# class code to make it accept this data?

Comment: The best technique I've found for troubleshooting problems like this, and for learning how serialization works, is to write a small test program that assembles an object in memory that looks like the object you expect to get from deserializing your original XML, and then serializes it.  If the resulting XML is different from the XML you're trying to deserialize, you can modify the classes until the output *does* match.  At that point, you should also be able to deserialize the original XML successfully.

Comment: I have been working on this little thing for a couple of hours now and I finally just gave up. I know this is the easy way out but sometimes I feel like it's okay to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played with it and finally got it to work:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class Plan
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public string Id { get; set; }


        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public List<Zone> Zones { get; set; }

        public Plan()
        {
            this.Id = string.Empty;
            this.Zones = new List<Zone>();
        }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class Zone
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public string Id { get; set; }


        public Zone()
        {
            this.Id = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

The change that finally made it work was adding (Namespace = "") to the Zone DataContract

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm reading this wrong (I don't do much WCF, but this is, at heart, an XML question), deserialising to a Zone array, rather than a List, should help.

You can then convert the array to the List, if you wish.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Plan
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Zone[] Zones { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    //assumes .NET 3.5+ for LINQ method, otherwise return new List<Zone>(Zones);
    public List<Zone> ZoneList { get { return Zones.ToList(); } }
}
[DataContract]
public class Zone
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

As a side point, your question title referes to an `ArrayList`, not a `List<T>`, which is a different, albeit similar, thing.